# Efficiently detecting shapes in a large image

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a huge circuit diagram that contains symbols like diodes, resistors, transistors.

I have to select symbols (based on a input template) from this image and highlight those using a rectangular bounding box. The symbols may be rotated (and scaled)  - but for now let's not consider scaling/rotation. There could be multiple symbols and lines in the same column/row.

The image size is 5600x3600. It is grayscale, converted to b/w and then the whole thing can be mentioned as 0s and 1s where 1 == black pixel. I think white pixels can be considered as "don't-cares"

What is the correct and faster method to do this?

I have a template image extracted from the larger image - for example "diode.png". Let's say that at least one symbol matches exactly without scaling or rotation.

Brute force template/matrix comparison approach works for me - but it is very slow.. takes 45 minutes (on the latest MBP-2.4ghz-Intel i5 / 8GB) to detect one exact match. I am using numpy wherever I could - but probably I am not using certain numpy iterators.

Unfortunately, I cannot do this outside python and cannot reduce the image size below 5600x3600 without making symbols unrecognisable.

Another way to put the problem is to : find all matching sub-matrices from a large matrix.

What is the correct and performing method to achieve the above?
I do not understand signal processing much - but could that help here? The template size (submatrix) in here is minimum 50x50

EDIT: OpenCV is not an option for me - skimage is available. However, please do not let that stop your inputs.

I cannot share the actual diagrams but a sample is here. For example diodes are  labeled as D1 and D2 here. The full diagram is as clear as this but on a canvas of 5600 x 3600

http://www.controlcircuitdiagram.com/diagramcircuitelectronic.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/electronic-circuits.jpg

I would also like to add that match_template from skimage works perfectly with smaller tiles extracted from the larger image

Comment: you can provide a sample image, so that someone may have more better idea and he would implement it on that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "[template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching)".

It's normally assumed that due to image noise and other factors, there will not be an exact match for the template. Instead you look for the image region with a minimal error score.

You can find an implementation using [normalized cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation) in scikit-image:

- http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_template.html
- http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#match-template

It would help if you added your existing code and a sample image and template.

Comment: Thanks, I have used this earlier - for some reason it does not work with the full (large) image. But it works perfectly for a smaller sample taken from the large image.
I never thought about the image noise factor that could be causing the problem with this: 
    ij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(result), result.shape)   . I'll give the "match result" another look to the results to see if something hidden in there. Thanks for the hint

Comment: It's hard to give specific advice without seeing your code. You will get much more better answers if you post your current method: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Large images took a lot of time to do template matching (and with rotation). Scaling was a parameter too - I used image pyramids for that. But to deal with a lot of noise and reduce the search space,  I had used Sum of Absolute differences to find the best scales for the image for a given template (in combination with some of my own parameters to determine the scale). Then used template matching with the probabilities to select the best results. Overall it correctly detected 95% of the images with zero-false-detections. The timing was not as large as 40 minutes - but 1-2 minutes(still huge).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [Sum of Absolute Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences) ? It is one of the simplest way to do template matching but it is also a brute force method.

I applied it for logo spotting in document images (A4, 300 dpi, 2500 * 3500 pixels). It is slow but it don't take 45 minutes ! In order to speed up you can split the image (chose overlapping zones in order to don't miss your symbol).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use opencv, it works for python as well.
 There you need to use essential functions:

> [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

then iterate through each contour

> for each(contours)

to obtain a sequence of points of contour, pointed by the variable 'contour'

> [approxPoly](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp)

[Here](https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/detecting-simple-shapes-in-an-image/), you find an interesting example

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention openCV is not an option for me. Skimage is okay. I'll update the question with that and will try these options in  skimage